# How to define key=var arguments in a snakemake profile yaml file

Tags: snakemake

Some of the snakemake arguments follow the key=value pattern. I would like to add them to the snakemake profile yaml file.

for example, the command line arguments should be stored in the snakemake profile.

`--default-resources mem=50 time=5`

I tried the two following options but it didn't work:

```
default-resources: "mem=50 time=5"
```

```
default-resources: 
  mem: 50
  time: 5
```

Problem continues for snakemake > 6.3 https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1186

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but since I believe it is a yaml file, I guess you should add a dash per line:

```
default-resources: 
  - mem: 50
  - time: 5
```

Comment: I've done this before, can confirm it works for resources.

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't work for me. With snakemake V5.26

Comment: What does not work? Snakemake can be strange when to use - and when to use _, so maybe try with `default_resources`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is the following syntax which is a bit at odds with the yaml definition.

```
default-resources: 
  - mem=50
  - time=5
```

Where the resources definitions are interpreted as strings.